# Do we absolutely need laplace transforms to solve $y'' + ky = F_0 \sin(\sqrt k t)$? Can't we use a different method?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I just saw someone solve $y'' + ky = F_0 \sin(\sqrt k t)$ using Laplace transforms and it was a real slog because it involved the unwieldy transforms of $t\sin(\sqrt k t)$ and $t\cos(\sqrt k t)$

($k, w,$ and $F_0$ are constants)

Is there a reason to do it this way instead of using a different method usable for second order linear DEs with constant coefficients? (For example finding the complementary solution and the nonhomogenous solution)?

Comment: Yes, you could use the method of undetermined coefficients. This involves first solving the homogeneous equation, and then guessing at a particular solution. In this case, since the forcing function is a homogeneous solution of the equation, your guess would need to be $y_p(t) = At\sin(\sqrt{k}t) + Bt \cos(\sqrt k t)$, so there will still be a bit of ugly algebra, but it will likely be easier than the Laplace transform method.

Comment: @User8128 Great, thought I was misunderstanding something because I haven't been able to get the same answer with the method of undetermined coefficients, probably just a mistake somewhere in my calculation. Thank you!